# About useSelector equality check

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a question about redux useSelector equality check.

Refer to the React Redux Hook document (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates)

useSelector will do reference comparison to the return value and the previous value, force re-render if result appears to be different

I have a default blog store state like this

```
searcherParam: {
  keyword: '',
  categories: [],
  tags: [],
},
```

In the component, I use useSelector to retrieve the value

```
const searchParam = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searcherParam)
```

If I dispatch an action to update searcherParam with same value, the component will re-render because the return value is object (shallow compare)

So I retrieve the value by calling useSelector multiple times

```
const keyword = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searchrParam.keyword)
const categories = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searchrParam.categories)
const tags = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searchrParam.tags)
```

And I dispatch an action to update searcherParam with same value again

the component will not re-render

The point I can't understand is why component doesn't re-render ?

If useSelector do reference comparison, the categories value (array) should not be the same reference and the tags as well after dispatching

Do I have any misunderstanding ? Thanks

---

The reason about not re-rendering is because I save the categories (from redux store) via useState.

and use the useState's value to dispatch, so it is same reference...

here is the codesandbox, sorry for stupid question Q_Q

https://codesandbox.io/s/useselector-test-u6pvg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you do this :

```
const newKeyword = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searchrParam.keyword)
const newCategories = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searchrParam.categories)
const newTags = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searchrParam.tags)
```

This simply means that, you would want to have the latest value of each of them.

It does not translate to this :

```
searcherParam: {
  keyword: newKeyword,
  categories: newCategories,
  tags: newTags,
},
```

Because `searcherParam` will always be a new reference when the action is dispatched.

If you just want to re-render, if any of the 3 properties change, then you can simply fetch `state.searcherParam` and dispatch and achieve a re-render.

Fetching individual properties help when you would want to re-render only on `keyword` change. You do not want to re-render when either of `cateogories` or `tags` have changed.

Note in this case if you just fetch `searcherParam`, it would not care which of 3 properties have changed, you will get a re-render because it is a new reference.

This is what the docs have mentioned.

---

After discussion in comments.

Made a trivial implementation. Check below

[image: Edit redux-useSelector-useDispatch-Sample]

Comment: I know if I just fetch searcherParam, it would re-render cause it is a new reference.

Comment: The point I can’t understand is categories and tags are new reference too, why component would not re-render after dispatching

Comment: @Anymore So when you do `state.searcherParam`, it would not look for property change. It will just re-render.

If you have done `state.searcherParam.keyword`, then since we have fetched a single field value, it will only re-render when keyword changes.

Comment: If you mean the part of your answer in which you say component will not re-render, it will re-render because `searcherParam` would always be a new reference irrespective of its properties.

Comment: yeah I know state.searcherParam.keyword => only re-render when keyword changes, but how about the state.searcherParam.categories ? From my understanding, categories would be a new reference too, why component would not re-render ?

Comment: It would re-render in that case as well.

Comment: @Anymore Can you share a codesandbox which replicates your problem?
Also how do you detect whether there is a re-render or not?

Comment: The reason about not re-rendering is because I save the categories (from redux store) via useState.
and use the useState's value to dispatch, so it is same reference... sorry for stupid question. I add codesandbox link in my question

Answer (score 0):

Rather than selecting the above properties separately, they all can be obtained via deconstructing the `searchrParam` object:

```
const { newKeyword, newCategories, newTags } = useSelector(
     state => state.Blog.searchrParam
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you trying to add same value to the store and also you are referring directly from the store (state.Blog.searchParam), your code below will not cause re-render.

```
const searchParam = useSelector(state => state.Blog.searcherParam)
```

In order to make it to re-render, you can try below

```
const searchParam = useSelector(state => ({keyword: state.keyword, categories: state.categories, tags: state.tags}))
```

The above code will always try to re-render, since the returned object reference will not be same.